# JxBrowser LoadURL/LoadHTML

Tags: javascript, java, html, jxbrowser

I am having issues with JxBrowser when loading html files from my local directory. I have used loadHTML and loadURL in my project. In the below instance, when I use loadURL inside a browserInvokeAndWait method I am finding it takes too long and is not able to reference my Javascript library as needed. I am trying to enable buttons in my loaded page, however I cannot access any of the loaded elements as the page cannot load itself. Code is below:
    package src.java;

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.Browser;
import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.Callback;
import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.JSValue;
import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.dom.By;
import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.dom.DOMDocument;
import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.dom.DOMElement;
import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.dom.events.DOMEvent;
import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.dom.events.DOMEventListener;
import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.dom.events.DOMEventType;
import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.events.FinishLoadingEvent;
import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.events.LoadAdapter;
import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.events.ScriptContextAdapter;
import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.events.ScriptContextEvent;
import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.swing.BrowserView;

public class VisualFrame {

public VisualFrame(final Graph<GNode> dagGraph, final GNode rootGNode, final Browser browser, final BrowserView view, final JFrame frame){
    frame.setTitle("Visualisation");
    frame.setResizable(false);

    browser.addScriptContextListener(new ScriptContextAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void onScriptContextCreated(ScriptContextEvent event) {
            Browser browser = event.getBrowser();
            JSValue window = browser.executeJavaScriptAndReturnValue("window");
            window.asObject().setProperty("java", new CytoData(dagGraph, rootGNode));
            JSValue document = browser.executeJavaScriptAndReturnValue("document");
            document.asObject().setProperty("java", new Graph<GNode>());
        }
    });


    browser.addLoadListener(new LoadAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void onFinishLoadingFrame(FinishLoadingEvent event) {
            if (event.isMainFrame()) {
                System.out.println("Has Reached");
                event.getBrowser().executeJavaScript("var nodes = [];"
                        + "var myArray = new Array();"
                        + "myArray = new Array(window.java.getNodes());"
                        + "var nodes = myArray.toString();"
                        + "nodes = nodes.replace('[','');"
                        + "nodes = nodes.replace(']','');"
                        + "nodes = nodes.split(',');"
                        + "var cy = cytoscape({"
                        + "container: document.getElementById('cy'),"
                        + "boxSelectionEnabled: false,"
                        + "autounselectify: true,"
                        + "style: cytoscape.stylesheet()"
                        + ".selector('node')"
                        + ".css({'content': 'data(id)'})"
                        + ".selector('edge')"
                        + ".css({'curve-style': 'bezier','target-arrow-shape': 'triangle',"
                        + "'width': 4,'line-color': '#ddd','target-arrow-color': '#ddd'})"
                        + ".selector('.highlighted')"
                        + ".css({'background-color': '#61bffc','line-color': '#61bffc',"
                        + "'target-arrow-color': '#61bffc',"
                        + "'transition-property': 'background-color, line-color, target-arrow-color',"
                        + "'transition-duration': '0.5s'}),"
                        + "});"
                        + "var elementCounter = 0;"
                        + "for (i = 0; i < window.java.getSizeOfDAG(); i++) {"
                        + "var currentNode = nodes[i].trim();"
                        + "var eles = cy.add({group: 'nodes', data: { id:currentNode}});"
                        + "elementCounter++}"
                        + "elements: [eles];");
                event.getBrowser().executeJavaScript("for (i = 0; i < window.java.getSizeOfDAG(); i++) {"
                        + "var newCurrentNode = nodes[i].trim();"
                        + "window.alert(newCurrentNode);"
                        + "var holdArray = window.java.getLinkedNodeIDs(newCurrentNode);"
                        + "var targetNodes = holdArray.toString();"
                        + "targetNodes = targetNodes.replace('[','');"
                        + "targetNodes = targetNodes.replace(']','');"
                        + "targetNodes = targetNodes.split(',');"
                        + "for (x = 0; x < targetNodes.length; x++){"
                        + "var targetString = targetNodes[x].trim();"
                        + "eles = cy.add({group: 'edges', data: { id: elementCounter, source:newCurrentNode.trim(), target:targetString.trim()}});"
                        + "elementCounter++;"
                        + "cy.layout({"
                        + "name: 'breadthfirst', "
                        + "fit: true, "
                        + "directed: true,"
                        + "padding: 15,"
                        + "spacingFactor: 1,"
                        + "avoidOverlap: true}).run();"
                        + "}}");
            }
        }
    });

    Browser.invokeAndWaitFinishLoadingMainFrame(browser, new Callback<Browser>(){
        @Override
        public void invoke(Browser arg0) {
            browser.loadURL("file:///home/mbax4jo2/workspace/EditDistanceVisualisation/src/src/web/index.html");
        }
    });




    InputStream urlStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("../web/UserInputForm.html");

    String html = null;

    try (BufferedReader urlReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader (urlStream))) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        String row;
        while ((row = urlReader.readLine()) != null) {
                builder.append(row);
        }
        html = builder.toString();
    }  catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

    final String loadHTMLPath = html;

    DOMDocument document = browser.getDocument();
    final DOMElement documentElement = document.getDocumentElement();
    System.out.println(browser.getHTML());
    if (documentElement != null) {
        try{
            DOMElement element = documentElement.findElement(By.id("resetBtn"));
            element.addEventListener(DOMEventType.OnClick, new DOMEventListener() {
                public void handleEvent(DOMEvent event) {
                    System.out.println(event);
                    browser.loadURL("file:///home/mbax4jo2/workspace/EditDistanceVisualisation/src/src/web/UserInputForm.html");
                    new UserInput(browser, view, frame);
                }
            }, false);
        }catch(NullPointerException e){
            System.out.println("NULL");
        }

    }

    if (documentElement != null) {
        try{
            DOMElement element = documentElement.findElement(By.id("finishBranchBtn"));
            element.addEventListener(DOMEventType.OnClick, new DOMEventListener() {
                public void handleEvent(DOMEvent event) {
                    browser.loadHTML(loadHTMLPath);
                }
            }, false);
        }catch(NullPointerException e){
            System.out.println("NULL");
        }

    }

    if (documentElement != null) {
        try{
            DOMElement element = documentElement.findElement(By.id("backBtn"));
            element.addEventListener(DOMEventType.OnClick, new DOMEventListener() {
                public void handleEvent(DOMEvent event) {
                    browser.loadHTML(loadHTMLPath);
                }
            }, false);
        }catch(NullPointerException e){
            System.err.println("Caught Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }

    }

    if (documentElement != null) {
        try{
            DOMElement element = documentElement.findElement(By.id("nextBtn"));
            element.addEventListener(DOMEventType.OnClick, new DOMEventListener() {
                public void handleEvent(DOMEvent event) {
                    browser.loadHTML(loadHTMLPath);
                }
            }, false);
        }catch(NullPointerException e){

            System.err.println("Caught Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }

    }
}
}
```

I don't quite understand why the loadURL takes so long, and when I attempt the loadHTML technique, I find this doesn't work. I am missing something quite fundamental in regards to the difference between these two methods.

Thanks in advance, 
Jack

EDIT 
Chromium.log 
Feb 27, 2018 1:45:42 PM com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ipc.a run
SEVERE: [0227/134542.952445:ERROR:browser_process_stub.cpp(61)] Not implemented reached in virtual ProfileManager *BrowserProcessStub::profile_manager()

IPC Log
- FINE: WRITE: LoadURLMessage{type=LoadURL, uid=796, url='file:///home/mbax4jo2/workspace/EditDistanceVisualisation/src/src/web/index.html', frameId=-1, extraHeaders='null', postData='null', SocketInfo{cid=0, bid=0, channelType=Browser}

- FINE: READ:  OnHandleLoadMessage{type=OnHandleLoad, uid=9, url='file:///home/mbax4jo2/workspace/EditDistanceVisualisation/src/src/web/index.html', loadType=5, loadPolicy=2, isRedirect=false, isBackForward=false, cancel=false, SocketInfo{cid=0, bid=0, channelType=Render}
- FINE: WRITE: OnHandleLoadMessage{type=OnHandleLoad, uid=9, url='file:///home/mbax4jo2/workspace/EditDistanceVisualisation/src/src/web/index.html', loadType=5, loadPolicy=2, isRedirect=false, isBackForward=false, cancel=false, SocketInfo{cid=0, bid=0, channelType=Render}
- FINE: READ:  OnShouldBeginRequestMessage{type=OnShouldBeginRequest, uid=878, browserContextId=-1, url='file:///home/mbax4jo2/workspace/EditDistanceVisualisation/src/src/web/index.html', method='GET', resourceType=0, cancel=false, SocketInfo{cid=0, bid=-1, channelType=Main}
  Feb 27, 2018 1:45:42 PM 
  com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ipc.MemoryChannelWriter run
- FINE: WRITE: OnShouldBeginRequestMessage{type=OnShouldBeginRequest, uid=878, browserContextId=-1, url='file:///home/mbax4jo2/workspace/EditDistanceVisualisation/src/src/web/index.html', method='GET', resourceType=0, cancel=false, SocketInfo{cid=0, bid=-1, channelType=Main}
- FINE: READ:  OnDidCommitProvisionalLoadForFrameMessage{type=OnDidCommitProvisionalLoadForFrame, uid=879, frameId=2, url='file:///home/mbax4jo2/workspace/EditDistanceVisualisation/src/src/web/index.html', isMainFrame=true, transitionType=1, SocketInfo{cid=0, bid=0, channelType=Browser}
- FINE: READ:  OnDidFinishLoadMessage{type=OnDidFinishLoad, uid=889, frameId=2, validatedURL='file:///home/mbax4jo2/workspace/EditDistanceVisualisation/src/src/web/index.html', isMainFrame=true, SocketInfo{cid=0, bid=0, channelType=Browser}
- FINE: READ:  OnRunJavaScriptDialogMessage{type=OnRunJavaScriptDialog, uid=890, dialogId=1, originURL='file:///home/mbax4jo2/workspace/EditDistanceVisualisation/src/src/web/index.html', acceptLang='', messageType=0, messageText='bbc', defaultPromptText='', isReload=false, SocketInfo{cid=0, bid=0, channelType=Browser}

Comment: Could you share some logs like described at the following link: https://jxbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/solutions/articles/9000013125

Comment: @DmitryKhovyakov I have done the log files as you have said and have posted some of the output in the original question (the content relating to loadURL within the log files). There was one severe issue with the profile manager.

Comment: @DmitryKhovyakov I also get a timeout error - event.getMessage() = Uncaught java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException when loading the URL

Comment: @DmitryKhovyakov reckon you have any insight to the load issues I am having?

Comment: It seems that point is no longer reproducible in JxBrowser 6.18. Try updating to the 6.18.